# Iterate through JSON response Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject C#

Tags: c#, json

I don't want to create a class to deserialise the response as it may vary in the future.

I've tried with a few ways trying to access the data I want but I dont really know how to access the items in the json response.

```
obj {{
  "type": "regular",
  "response": {
    "usable": [
      {
        "id": "897",
        "name": "John Doe",
        "owner": {
          "id": "2",
          "username": "jdoe",
          "firstname": "john",
          "lastname": "doe"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "657",
        "name": "Karen Whiner",
        "owner": {
          "id": "3",
          "username": "kwhiner",
          "firstname": "karen",
          "lastname": "whiner"
        }
      },
  },
  "error_code": 0,
  "error_msg": "",
  "warnings": [],
  "timestamp": 74772822
}}
```

What I need:

Console.WriteLine:

id: 897 - name: john doe - username: jdoe
id: 657 - name: Karen Whiner - username: kwhiner

.
etc.

What I've tried:

```
var jsonString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(jsonString);


DataSet dataSet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(jsonString);
DataTable dataTable = dataSet.Tables["response"];

foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine(row["id"] + " - " + row["name"]);
}

---


JObject stuff = JObject.Parse(jsonString);

foreach (JProperty rate in stuff)
{
    Console.WriteLine(rate.Name + ": " + rate.Value);
}
```

any suggestions?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the json you have posted is not right.. but i am assuming it has something to do with copy/paste and berevity.

You have different options but if you want to go with dynamic/object deserialization, you can do this to Print one of the lines.

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(text);
var usableList = obj["response"]["usable"];
Console.WriteLine($"id: {usableList[0]["id"]} - name: {usableList[0]["name"]} - username: {usableList[0]["owner"]["username"]}");

//prints
id: 897 - name: John Doe - username: jdoe
```

What I would recommend is creating a class to deserialize your json to. that way you can use Linq and for loops to go through all your usable list.

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public Response response { get; set; }
    public int error_code { get; set; }
    public string error_msg { get; set; }
    public object[] warnings { get; set; }
    public int timestamp { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public Usable[] usable { get; set; }
}

public class Usable
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Owner owner { get; set; }
}

public class Owner
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }
}

// and deserialization and printing would be like this,

var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(text);
foreach (var item in obj.response.usable)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"id: {item.id} - name: {item.name} - userid: {item.owner.username}");
}

// prints:
id: 897 - name: John Doe - userid: jdoe
id: 657 - name: Karen Whiner - userid: kwhiner
```

Comment: thank you, I've tested and for some reason it only prints the first row, I've tried to iterate through it with             foreach (var i in usableList) then Console.WriteLine("id: {usableList[0]["id"]}); but i am not getting the data info, how can I iterate through each row/value?

Comment: if you are using `foreach(var i in usableList)` .. then you have to use variable `i` in the `Console.WriteLine`. `Console.WriteLine($"id: {i["id"]}")`. Also. you have to use $ for string interpolation. Example i wrote iterates through all the usables and prints like i showed.